# Taking advantage of the name of a variable in Stata

Tags: string, variables, stata

I´m using Stata and I have a set of variables named `cal1`, `cal2`, `cal3` and so on until `cal21`. For every line of my dataset, i could have more or less `cal*` variables as non-missing (I designed the dataset with a `reshape wide`). I want to generate a new variable that returns the maximum name of variable `cal*` available for each line that is non-missing. For example, if line 1 has until `cal3` as non- missing , this variable returns `cal3`; for the line 2 if i have `cal1`, `cal2` and `cal6`, I want `cal6`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: dont do that in Stata

Comment: The most straightforward way is to compute it before the reshape. Then, don't reshape wide, because experienced Stata users generally agree that, with few exceptions, Stata makes it much more straightforward to accomplish complex analyses, or even simple tasks like the one you are attempting, using a long layout of your data rather than a wide layout of the same data.

Comment: @Noobie That comment might be helpful or interesting if you gave a reason.

Comment: An explicit data example and some attempt at code are expected in good questions. The title of the question isn't really informative about the nature of the problem, which is to find the last non-missing variable in each observation. Systematic naming makes it a little easier but that's not central to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier to accomplish with data in long <del>format</del> layout, but it is doable with wide data too with a loop:

```
gen max_cal = "none"
forvalues v=1/21 {
    replace max_cal = "cal`v'" if !missing(cal`v')
}
```

This will update the `max_cal` variable each time there's a higher one not missing.

Comment: "format" is over-loaded in Stata (manifestly not your fault!). Experienced Stata users will recognise immediately what you are talking about but I like Clyde Schechter's example of referring to long layout and wide layout.

Comment: Just to note that if the variable names were irregular we would just use `foreach`.

Comment: @NickCox An excellent point. I think this a list of such words would make an excellent FAQ.

Comment: @L.Vaiz Accepting DImitriy's answer if it helped would be good for his reputation and yours too. Otherwise you should flag any remaining difficulties.